# Cannot partitioning table on mysql

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, database-partitioning

When I run `alter table` for partitioning on innodb table I got this error on Mysql 5.7:

```
Foreign keys are not yet supported in conjunction with partitioning
```

knowing that I already `drop foreign key` of this table, and `drop foreign key` where the id of this table is.

here is my table schema now:

```
| record | CREATE TABLE `record` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `altitude` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `counter` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `details` longtext,
  `deviation` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `engine` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `event` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fuel_level` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `gsm_level` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `latitude` double NOT NULL,
  `longitude` double NOT NULL,
  `satellite` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `speed` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` time NOT NULL,
  `treated` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `id_driver` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_vehicle_device` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_ai9y9d52lx1xvtaiv3w0x60a5` (`id_driver`),
  KEY `FK_ilwlg0mt87bxyemx4tov1elni` (`id_vehicle_device`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

Comment: Please explain what `PARTITIONing` you want to do.  I _may_ try to talk you out of partitioning -- most uses of such do not provide any benefit.

Answer (score 5):

From [Restrictions and Limitations on Partitioning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-limitations.html):

> **Foreign keys not supported for partitioned InnoDB tables.  Partitioned tables using the InnoDB storage engine do not support foreign keys.** More specifically, this means that the following two statements are true:
>
> - No definition of an InnoDB table employing user-defined partitioning may contain foreign key references; no InnoDB table whose definition contains foreign key references may be partitioned.
> - No InnoDB table definition may contain a foreign key reference to a user-partitioned table; no InnoDB table with user-defined partitioning may contain columns referenced by foreign keys.

Comment: As I said, I have already drop foreign keys from record. still got the error

Comment: I test it on the link you gave me and worked, but on my server it won't work, even on my laptop on mysql I have I got the same error

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can find missed referenced or referring table by this SQL

```sql
WITH t AS (
SELECT  TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, CONSTRAINT_NAME,
        GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION) AS COLUMN_NAMES,
        MIN(REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME) AS REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,
        GROUP_CONCAT(REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME ORDER BY POSITION_IN_UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT) AS REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAMES
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE   REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME IS NOT NULL
        AND TABLE_SCHEMA = <your_schema>
GROUP BY
        TABLE_NAME, CONSTRAINT_NAME
ORDER BY
        TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, CONSTRAINT_NAME)
SELECT  *
FROM    t
WHERE   table_name = 'record' OR referenced_table_name = 'record'
```

Answer (score -1):

This means that no user-partitioned InnoDB table may contain foreign key references or **columns referenced by foreign key**