# Mysql partition in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a large number of data in my incidents table with a column named year. I want to create partitions based on the year column. I tried to [brokenice/laravel-mysql-partition](https://packagist.org/packages/brokenice/laravel-mysql-partition) but it gives me an error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1506 Foreign keys are not yet supported in conjunction with partitioning
```

With the above package, I tried to create partion with the code:

```
Schema::partitionByYears('my_table', 'year', 2000, 2010);
```

**N.B.** I have only one primary key in my table which is id. Year column is not a foreign key in my migration or nor an index. Tried it by converting to an index column but no luck.

Comment: You must not use foreign key on the table at all, this might help, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45962503/cannot-partitioning-table-on-mysql

Comment: Thanks. I was using multiple foreign keys in my migration.